# How to center a div when I press the buttons in the menu?

Tags: html, css, web

As you can see in my website: http://erdemcalikoglu.cf/   I have the menu on the top of the screen but my problem is: when I press the 2nd and the 4th button the conten is not centered. Can you help me with that please?[I want this when I press the SERVICES button on menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irmF2.jpg)

[but it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPdvD.jpg)

Comment: [Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and that means your code. Linking a website or page is not considered a good practice, since they keep on changing and cannot be looked up by other users having same question. Beautiful site anyway

Answer (score 3):

Remove the padding left from .iletisim p, Corrected code below

```
.iletisim p {
position: absolute;
text-align: left;
color: white;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
z-index: 1;
font-size: 30px;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 0px; }
```

try this

Comment: Change padding-left:0 and try

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide enough info but by using Inspect Element, you need to add a width of 100% to your text or the container that it is in. Right now, it's centering the text in the provided width - which is dynamic upon your text. When you make the width 100%, it's setting the text container to fit the screen size 100%.

Add this to your CSS:

```
.servis p {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I did that but nothing changed

Comment: provide your working code here? within your question above...?